# When does the .append() method occurs?

Tags: jquery

I was wondering, when does this method is applied exactly, for example if I have an append inside a for loop with a set of instructions and one of the instruction is to apply a function onClick after being appended to the DOM,  :

```
        for(i=0;i<somelength;i++){

           $('div element').append(createButton(text_of_button,href_of_button,id_of_button));

           $(id_of_button).click(function(){

           //Some logic here...

           });
        }
```

The buttons are created succesfully and their link works fine, but the .click(...) doesn't do anything. Am I missing something ? Does append happens on the fly or something else?
ps: id_of_button = '#someButton'

The createButton implementation:

```
function createButton(buttonText,hrefLink,id) {
    var button = '<a href="'+hrefLink+'"class="ui-btn ui-btn-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-up-c" data-role="button" data-theme="c"' + '' + 'id="' + id + '"' + '>' +
        '<span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all">' +
        '<span class="ui-btn-text">' + buttonText + '</span>' +
        '</span>' +
        '</a>';
    return button;
}
```

Comment: `append()` itself is not a function

Comment: Do you mean `$('element').append()`?

Comment: It works immediately. http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/eCD7J/

Comment: @putvande - of course it is, note the parenthesis !

Comment: Fair enough.. But it won't append to the DOM unless OP has defined the function somewhere else.

Comment: So what is value of: `id_of_button` ???

Comment: @h2ooooooo yes, I just edited, thanks for noticing

Comment: IDs must be unique, this seems to be your issue

Comment: @putvande - it's attached to $.fn, so it needs a jQuery collection as context, but it's still a function, but that's nitpicking really.

Comment: @A.Wolff ID's are unique, I dont think that's my issue, but thanks

Comment: Just check if not already done if click handler is fired or not. ??? Maybe this is `//Some logic here...` part of code which is failing

Comment: @A.Wolff yes, I checked but it's not being triggered. I don't know why.

Comment: `alert($(id_of_button).length)`  result?

Comment: So element doesn't exist, your selector is wrong

Comment: @A.Wolff thank you, will see whats wrong.

Comment: $(id_of_button).click(funtion(){ is there a typo in "function"?

Comment: @Enam I had a typo here but in my code I didn't, but thanks

Comment: @A.Wolff, in the DOM when I load the page, I check the HTML, and the button has been created with the unique ID, but the `$(id_of_button').length` still is `0` is there an explanation ?

Comment: provide generated HTML code for the button (exact one, not a pseudo one) and the same for value of: `id_of_button` I'm quite sure your selector doesn't match or you are adding button after it in some dynamic way

Comment: The code shown wouldn't create unique ids, because `id_of_button` isn't changed by any of the code shown. The problem must be in the code that you don't show...

Comment: So you have duplicate IDs. I was thinking you were updating global variable `id_of_button` inside createButton function, but no...

Comment: Why dupiclate Ids, if the parameter that is send to the id_of_button are always different

Comment: Duplicate ids because (again) for the code shown `id_of_button` is never changed. But for the code you have shown I believe my answer (below) applies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create an element with `id` equal to whatever is in `id_of_button` then to select the new element and assign a click you would need to use:

```
$("#" + id_of_button).click(function() {
```

You said "ps: `id_of_button = '#someButton'`. I'd suggest you set the id to `"someButton"` *without* the `#` and then you can select the element like I've shown above. If your id does actually contain a `#` at the beginning as in `<button id="#someButton">` then to select it with jQuery you'd need to escape the `#` like this:

```
$("#\\#someButton")
```

...which with your variable would be like this:

```
$("#\\" + id_of_button).click(function() [
```

Comment: OP said id_of_button string already contains the hash  `ps: id_of_button = '#someButton'`

Comment: @A.Wolff - I know, but the same variable is used in both places, and OP also said `$(id_of_button).length` is `0`, so without seeing the implementation of the `buttonCreatedByString()` function I think this is the most likely explanation.

Comment: Ya, seems fair enough

Comment: @nnnnnn Thanks for the recommendations, but this is not the answer for my question, anyhow I do consider this a good advice, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. But does your element's id have a `#` in it or not? I don't think we can help you any further unless you show us the implementation of `buttonCreatedByString()`, and/or create a demo at http://jsfiddle.net.

Comment: @nnnnnn, There you have the createButton function

Comment: I mean, I could generate a function and handle the onclick trigger on the same string where I'm making the button

Comment: OK, for the code you've now added to the question I stand by my answer. You are using the same variable value as the id of the element and then as the selector, but you'd need to add a `#` to the beginning of the selector to have jQuery treat it as an id.